# Identify origin of an observable event on subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a `BehaviorSubject<Array<user>>` (`userListSub$`) state that is updated from various places.

For example,

- when I click Follow on a user
- when I click Unfollow on a user
- when I favorite a user

The same state is being subscribed in different components. I would like a particular component to not react to an event emitted by the state (`userListSub$`) if the event was triggered when I favorite the user.

I know we can store the origin of the event also in the state like this,
`userListSub$.next({ data: user, origin: userList })`
and check for the origin where I subscribe.

Is there a better way to identify or ignore the event on particular subscriptions?
Am I thinking in the right direction? If not, can you suggest a better way?

Comment: By practice, the observable pattern abstracts away the source of the event. So yes, you should store it in the event.

Comment: check async pipes on the html

Comment: Part of the benefits of using observables is that you don’t have to worry about what caused the state to change, you can simply subscribe and receive the most up to date value. I’m curious about the use case you have in mind where you don’t want a subscriber to receive and update based on the source of the update. If you provide more info, maybe we can suggest an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may to try a slightly different model.

Suppose you have 3 components: C1, C2 and C3. All the components react to the events "Click Follow on a user" and "Click Unfollow on a user".

Only C1 and C2 though react to the event "favorite a user".

In this case, you can model 2 streams of events, and therefore 2 `BehaviourSubject`s, let's call them `S1` and `S2`, one that notifies "Click Follow on a user" and "Click Unfollow on a user" events and the other that notifies the "favorite a user" event.

Then you can create an `Observable`, let's call it `Obs1 = merge(S1, S2)` that merges `S1` and `S2`.

Now, C1 and C2 can subscribe to `Obs1` while C3 can subscribe to `S1`.

In this way you should be able to achieve your objective and, at least in my opinion, this is a more idiomatic reactive way to achieve it than adding the id of the source.